# How to pass command line argument as a password to gradle project?

Tags: java, gradle, command-line, build.gradle

Hi i want to pass username and password as a command line argument and i am able to do that but my problem is when i entered password it get displayed on command line. I want to display in ***** format.

Comment: that's not possible.

Comment: That probably depends on the platform and would be independent of Java and gradle (there are batch/shell scripts that do that on the net, so look for those).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your console, the following code will get the Console object and will take input while masking the console echo.

```
Console console = System.console();
char password[] = console.readPassword("Enter password: ");
console.printf("You entered: %s%n", new String(password));
```

Note that if you are using an IDE with a built-in console (IE Eclipse), this may not work.